# Как начать проигрывать mp3 файл, на jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Хочу, чтобы при вызове определенной функции, начал играть mp3 файл, как реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал через [эту](http://www.sean-o.com/jquery/jmp3/) штуку.

Если на сайте [www.putit.ru](http://www.putit.ru) нажать shift+p - увидите прикол, ради которого спрашивал все))

Answer (score 1):

В сети встречал несколько решений, но чаще положительные отзывы читал о [плагине jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/).  [Читаем про плагин на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/112776/)